# What's a pair bluetooth headsets that doesn't vibrate/make noise when low battery?

Tags: bluetooth

I sometimes listen to audio when I sleep.

Main Question: What's a bluetooth headset product that will not make noises/vibrate when low battery?  No noise, including the device telling you "battery very low" with a voice, and also no beeping, no vibrating notification when battery low

More details:

**Budget**: Less than 100$

**Form factor of bluetooth headset**: Preferably something like this [https://www.amazon.com/LG-Electronics-HBS-750-Bluetooth-Wireless/dp/B00FO0IHMY/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1485926696&sr=8-2&keywords=bluetooth+headset+lg](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FO0IHMY)

Since it would stay on you even when you sleep

**Why a simple search did not work for answering my question:** Specifications for bluetooth headset products do not state whether or not there is a "battery very low" sound or vibration when the battery is low.

**Other Specifications**: If it does not make beeping sounds when you adjust the volume with its buttons, that would be good too obviously because the application is for sleeping.

Comment: To answer your question.  A product that will  not make a noise or vibrate would be a headset without a low battery warning/indicator.

If you have any other questions, feel free to update your question to indicate as such.

Comment: Could you narrow your question down?  E.g. what's your budget, how much battery life do you need, what "form factor" do you want (ear buds, headphones) etc... It makes finding a suitable recommendation much easier. :)